# Maintenance vs regression testing

Tags: testing

Could any one explain to me the difference between maintenance tests and regression tests? The too types are used after a modification in the software.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you researched the question? What have you found?

Answer (score 0):

There's some differences between Maintenance testing and Regression testing. I'll outline what each do below.

Regression testing includes:

- Testing Software that is in development
- Testing of all sorts of functionalities and features in detail.
- Requires a large amount of time, and resources.

Maintenance testing includes:

- Testing software outside the development cycle (The software has been deployed)
- Usually used for confirming if repairs have been effective or not.
- Really isn't time driven, but still need some sort of man power to run tests.